# When was the Fermat number $F_{32}$ shown to be composite?

Tags: number-theory

The first few Fermat numbers are $F_{0}=2^{2^0}+1=3$, $F_{1}=2^{2^1}+1=5$, $F_{2}=2^{2^2}+1=17$.

I read that $F_5$ through $F_{32}$ have been shown to be composite. And right now $F_{33}$ is the smallest Fermat number whose primality is unknown.

My question is: When was $F_{32}$ shown to be composite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short Google search yields the page http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html, which says a factor of the 32nd Fermat number was found in 1963 by Wrathall and that only one prime factor is known.

Comment: And the Wrathall paper is [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-086/S0025-5718-1964-0163868-9/S0025-5718-1964-0163868-9.pdf).

Comment: The URL given is now a 404 - most recent archive I could find is at http://web.archive.org/web/20161028080351/http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html